# Prism CustomRegionAdapter, allow multiple

Tags: wpf, telerik

This is a short question, but needs a long explanation. In short, in our WPF-application we have a [Teleriks RadTabbedWindow](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtabbedwindow/overview), that is databbound to a list of viewmodels and if user clicks new-tab-button we add a new viewmodel to the datasource. Each ViewModel is connected to its view, with DataTemplate (see below), nothing special.

In the controls (below) we have bound Loaded-event [(like this)](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/wiki/CallMethodAction) . The problem is that it only fires on the first Tab. Lets say we create 3 SearchHolderViewModels, ie 3 instances of same control, one in each tab. . **I only get an OnControlLoaded for the first created Control. With the code below I "manually" trigger the LoadedCommand and that works. But Is this the way to to it? And why do we only get the event first time,as I see it the 3 instances are not related**

We are using [Teleriks RadTabbedWindow](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtabbedwindow/overview), like so, markup for MainWindow:

```
 <telerik:RadTabbedWindow x:Class="Porter.Application.Views.MainWindow"
    ...
    ItemsSource="{Binding WindowTabs}"                          
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWindowTab, Mode=TwoWay}">

<telerik:RadTabbedWindow.Resources>
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type acc:SearchHolderViewModel}">
        <acc:SearchHolderView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type hello:HelloWorldViewModel}">
        <hello:HelloWorldView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:RadTabbedWindow.Resources>
```

In ViewModel, properties

```
private ObservableCollection<ITabbedWindowContent> _windowTabs;
public ObservableCollection<ITabbedWindowContent> WindowTabs
{
    get => _windowTabs;
    set { SetProperty(ref _windowTabs, value); }
}

private ITabbedWindowContent _selectedWindowTab;
public ITabbedWindowContent SelectedWindowTab
{
    get => _selectedWindowTab;
    set { SetProperty(ref _selectedWindowTab, value); }
}
```

ViewModel, ctor and OnTab-added-handler:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    NewTabWindowCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(OnNewTabWindow);
    WindowTabs = new ObservableCollection<ITabbedWindowContent>() { new SearchHolderViewModel() };
}

private void OnNewTabWindow(string viewName)
{  
    switch (viewName)
    {
        case Navigation.RB_SearchAccountsView:
            var searachHolderVM = new SearchHolderViewModel(_eventAggregator);
            WindowTabs.Add(searachHolderVM);
            searchHolderVM.LoadedCommand.Execute();//added to simulate Loaded-event
            break;
        case Navigation.SA_HelloWorldView: 
            WindowTabs.Add(new HelloWorldViewModel()); 
            break;     
    } 
}
```

Comment: The `DataTemplate` and `UserControl` is reused for all instances.

Comment: @mm8 Ok, that makes sense in most cases I guess. However if I do a search in one of the Search-tabs its textbox-value and search results are unique for that tab. How would I do to have a separate control for each tab. Is the way I solved it ok?

Comment: Only one view is displayed at a time so I don't really see what your issue is. Could you elaborate please? You don't need several instances of the view. You should bind to properties of the view model and the bindings will be updated when you switch tabs.

Comment: Ok, the application can be compared to a web browser in this regard. If you hit the [+]-button in for example Chrome, a new Tab is created and your startpage is loaded, it is completely separated from your previous one.

Comment: So? You still only see one tab at a time in a `TabControl`.

Comment: my problem is that I dont get a Loaded-event, on the other tabs (except the first). So my question is, is the solution above correct (it works, but I'd rather just get the Loaded-event when control is loaded)